# Why am I getting syntax error on the return line?

Tags: python, syntax, return

Why am I getting syntax error on the return line?

```py
def with_argument_dump(function, *args, **kwargs):
    
def function_with_argument_dump(*args, **kwargs):
    argStr = ', '.join(map(str, args))
    kwargsStr = ','.join(f'{k}={v}' for k,v in kwargs.items()


    return (f"fct w/args:{function.__name__}({','.join([argStr,kwargsStr])})")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `)` in the `kwargsStr` line:

```py
kwargsStr = ','.join(f'{k}={v}' for k,v in kwargs.items()
```

Should be:

```py
kwargsStr = ','.join(f'{k}={v}' for k,v in kwargs.items())
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! It's the little stuff that adds up, cheers!

Comment: No problem! If you could just tag this as the answer and solve the question I'd appreciate it!